# What are the fast ways of leveling  without using platinum?

Tags: pocket-legends

I use the daily elixir and the Playa's potion which gives a 1.5 exp gain and I can only level up twice everyday. Will getting to Mt. Fang be at all helpful?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with mt. fang is, that, unless you're a healer or a very good archer, it's impossible to solo even the first level.

In later levels, it's almost impossible to take down the bosses without using platinum.

I would say that i would help if you can get a good group - however, I would recommend beating the first area, then doing XP runs in the second one (the crypt).

Being in a good guild can help, as they have high level members, who will help you if you need them.

Be warned that, soloing or trying to beat any boss is asking to die a lot (I did the first level with 2 ppl. who were using thrashers and we all died at least a dozen times or so).
However, if you are soloing, remember to take it very slowly and use as many potions as you need.

Another tip is to not buy the elixirs that cost gold unless you are a very good merchant, as they will eat through your cash and you really want to save that for some crafted items.

Answer (score -4):

Mt. Fang is like a hard level. Try to invite people that use elixir. It must be useful. The other player must use attack or defense elixir anyway.